# We want to use JSTL FMT Tags for i18n of JSP Pages but keep the language code folder in the url for SEO purposes

Tags: jsp, internationalization, jstl

We have JSP Pages internationalized with the JSP fmt tags. We also want to set the language in a cookie on the clients browser to maintain the language for all jsp pages. But in order to get good SEO for our languages we would need to maintain the http://website.com/en URL we have "/en/" for the english language and "/de" for german as well as "/it" for the italian language in our url. If i use the standard approach i will have a url like this "http://website.com/?lang=en" which google does not recomment. We want to keep our "folder" with the language code after the url. I am not sure if a servlet filter would work or what the best solutions would look like for this.

We are at a stage where we tested the standard approach which works but we always get the "?lang=" in the url and we try to figure out what we can do to let it look like a normal website with different language folders.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%--<fmt:setLocale value="en" /> --%>
<fmt:setLocale value="${param.lang}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="roma-vaticano_i18n" />
<html lang="${param.lang}">

...

<!--FIRST BLOCK-->
                       <div class="card-overview">
                        <div class="grid-container full">
                        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                        <div class="cell large-8 medium-12 small-12">
                      <figure class="card-overview--thumb"><a href="http://www.roma-vaticano.com/en/hotel-highlights/rome/"><img src="http://www.roma-vaticano.com/assets/images/rome-hotel-overview-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a></figure>
                            </div>
                        <div class="cell large-4 medium-12 small-12">
                            <div class="card-overview--content">
                        <h2 class="card-overview--content--title"><a href="http://www.roma-vaticano.com/en/hotel-highlights/rome/"><fmt:message key="Hotel.Highlights.overview.card.overview.title1"/></a></h2>
                        <p><fmt:message key="Hotel.Highlights.overview.card.overview.text1"/></p>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
...
```

The expected results are that the page will be translated in english because we only have the english resource bundle for the test but uses the "?lang=" extension on the URL which is OK. But as described we want to have different country folders like "en,de, it" after the url for better SEO on search engines.

Comment: I want to add the code for the "language switcher" this may be useful for other to know how we switch the languages on the pages. ''' <li><a href="?lang=de"><i class="flag flag--de"></i>Deutsch</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?lang=it"><i class="flag flag--it"></i>Italiano</a></li> '''

Comment: Hi BalusC, in the comment i included the code right after i asked the question where you can see that our menu generates URL's with "?=lang" in the menu. We would need to generate "/de/ or /en/or /it" and the filter would need to understand that the request is made for specific languages and displays the right language but keep the URL that we can use this for seo on the search engines.